# PHP Functions Question

Tags: php, function

I have two functions that i'm hoping i can put into one and can be called differently.

```
function my_function() {    
global $wpdb;
foreach( $wpdb->get_results( "MYSQL QUERY" ) as $key => $row)
{
    echo "'". $row->DAY . "'";
}
}

function my_function_two() {    
    global $wpdb;
    foreach( $wpdb->get_results( "MYSQL QUERY" ) as $key => $row)
    {
        echo "'". $row->TIME . "'";
    }
}
```

Notice how the only diffence between them both is the $row->TIME and $row->DAY, i'm using the exact same mysql query in both and was wondering if these two functions can be merged into one?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
function my_function($showDay = false) {    
  global $wpdb;
  foreach( $wpdb->get_results( "MYSQL QUERY" ) as $key => $row)
  {
    echo "'". ($showDay === true) ? $row->DAY : $row->TIME . "'";
  }
}
```

If you have to echo `$row->DAY`, call the function with `true` as parameter or leave it out to echo `$row->TIME`.

Example:

```
my_function(true); // for $row->DAY
my_function(); // for $row->TIME
```

Comment: Yeah, he probably meant that.. deleting my answer :)

Comment: With slight modifications to this answer, you could also have it echo both.

Comment: Thanks man, i knew it was simple, brain not functioning today. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

```
function my_function() {    
    global $wpdb;
    foreach( $wpdb->get_results( "MYSQL QUERY" ) as $key => $row)
    {
        echo "'". $row->DAY . "'";
        echo "'". $row->TIME . "'";
    }
}
```

Since you're being incredibly vague about what you mean by "merge", this is my best guess. If you could provide some sample output, I can re-do my answer to match.